# wp-json API 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress dashboard is extremely slow when doing things like updating posts. Chrome dev tools shows that requests to wp-json take very long and eventually return a 504 Gateway Timeout.

What could be causing this? How do I start to debug this?

Thanks!

[Chrome Dev Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkCuF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was because of a plugin (WooCommerce Services). I disabled the plugin and everything works smooth again. If you're having the same issue, I suggest disabling all your plugins and activating them one for one again to find the one causing troubled.